# How can I validate LDAP SSL Certificates Against the local truststore for .NET

Tags: ldap, ssl-certificate

I am trying to implement secure LDAP using SSL and I want to validate the servers certificate against the local keystore for which I have imported the certificate.

I realize I can do this:

```
ldapConnection.SessionOptions.VerifyServerCertificate =
            new VerifyServerCertificateCallback((con, cer) => true);
```

But that provides no authentication and will accept any cert. When I use SSL with WCF connections, it will automatically use my keystore by default without me having to supply a delegate at all, and that works perfect.

How can can direct the cert validation for an LDAP connection to my trust store? Can I implement the delegate, and then pass the X509Certificate arg to something else that will validate it against my store?

I have to use .NET 4.0

Comment: The piece of code you provided is for custom certificate validation implementation. Why not just allow LDAP client to do this for you automatically? In short, just remove this code and cert will be validated automatically by LDAP client.

Comment: That's exactly what I want to do, and its the reason for this question. It is exactly what I do with WCF. But apparently, the LDAP connection support does not look at the local truststore by default. The only way is to provide the callback, and all examples online always use the "return true" as the solution.